# AS3 NetConnection Recommended Usage

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

What is the recommended approach for using the NetConnection class?

1. Repeated usage, use one NetConnection instance to send all messages.

   - What's the behavior of a single NetConnection instance when you send a second message before the first one completes? Does it matter?
2. Create one NetConnection instance for every message.

Comment: If you need to use NetConnection a lot, then creating a new one all the time will cause some considerable memory churn. In our project we have lots of overlapping calls, so re-using a single global one doesn't work either so I am looking into using an pool of netconnections to avoid the memory churn. I'll post if I find a good definitive answer.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you should ask your instance for uncompleted operations. If your instance is not occupied feel free to reuse it. Otherwise create a new one.

Maybe [object pooling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pool_%28computer_science%29) is a keyword here